# SQL insert not working. 'category_id' cannot be null

Tags: laravel-5

I have this e-commerce course on Udemy that I have been trying to follow but get the same error, I reloaded the course and even tried to clone the code but still get the same error.

This is for PHP Laravel 5.5, trying to load products to database phpmyadmin products table.

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Categories') }}
  {{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'SelectCategory']) }}
</div>
```

The form should load the image and product description in the database under products, nothing is loading to phpmyadmin.

Error:

> 1048 Column 'category_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `products`
>   (`pro_name`, `pro_code`, `stock`, `pro_pr ▶"

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You want to insert data into a category_id column which does not allow to be null. You probably have a migration called: create_products_table. Please paste the migration code so we can help debug the issue.

Comment: Did you read the words in the error message? I'm not sure how **Column 'category_id' cannot be null** could be any more clear.

Comment: class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('status'); // its pending or done
            $table->string('total');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: Just posted the create orders table, still trying to learn how to code so I get that the id cannot be null but still trying to understand where and how to change it.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('pro_name');
            $table->string('pro_code');
            $table->string('pro_price');
            $table->string('pro_info');
            $table->string('stock');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('spl_price')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('new_arrival')->default('0')->nullable(); 
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty simple:

You are trying to write data into `caregory_id` column.

Unfortunately this column does not allow `null`.

You could change the propertys of your table and allow `category_id` to be null...

but i dont think thats what you want.

Therefor -->

You should just try not to pass `null` as `category_id` whenever creating something in this table.